Plantuml in overleaf is not working with Lualatex
As I understand this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76482628/3960850 the approach of using plantuml in overleaf should be quite easy. It should be enough to switch to Lualatex and it should work. However, the example as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{plantuml}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{plantuml}
  @startuml
  Alice -> Bob: Hello
  Alice <- Bob: Hi!
  @enduml
\end{plantuml}

\end{document}

throws 
What I am missing here?

probably unrelated but never use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} with lualatex

I can find no indication that overleaf supports plantuml.

@UlrikeFischer Ok. I took it for granted cause the referenced answer. But you are right, no other mention is possible to find.

I wonder if this is another AI hallucination ....

I have the same issue, the first time I came across a post saying it is possible to use PlantUML in overleaf was this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76482628/9690045
